# Posting a Curl request through php

Tags: php, curl, post

I wanted to send a post request to pilosa database. The request is like this -

curl localhost:10101/index/user/query
     -X POST
     -d 'Bitmap(frame="language", id=5)'.

How can i send the following request through php ?

Link for referrence : https://www.pilosa.com/docs/api-reference/

Comment: _“How can i send the following request through php ?”_ - you go read the cURL commandline documentation, to find out what the parameters mean. Then you go read the PHP cURL documentation, to find out what the corresponding options/calls are.

Comment: For your next questions please, go to the [Help Section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then, if you are sure your question fits the SO rules, read [How to Ask a question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to be able to make a good, well formed and on-topic question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have the [php curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) library available to you, you can query Pilosa with php's `file_get_contents` which is part of core php. The following php script should perform your example query:

```
<?php

$url = 'http://localhost:10101/index/user/query';
$data = 'Bitmap(frame="language", id=5)';

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => $data
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

var_dump($result);

?>
```

The Pilosa HTTP API documentation can be found at: https://www.pilosa.com/docs/api-reference/